# Which passport to apply for?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, uk-citizens, dual-nationality

My Great Great Grandma was born in Lahore (now Kashmire), when it was still art of the Raj. Her Father was in the Royal Horse Artillary, and originally came from Ireland.
A Couple of Questions.

1. Am I able to get a second passport?
2. If so, which Passport can I apply for? Indian - as this is where Lahore was, or Pakistani as this is where Lahore is now.

I know I cannot get both

Thanks

Comment: India does not recognize dual citizenship.you'll have to give up your existing passport (which you haven't told us about). Also Lahore isn't in Kashmir but in Punjab(Pakistan)

Comment: I don't know what benefit you will get by applying for a passport from either of those countries but I do know that going through the corrupt bureaucratic process to obtain a possport in either of them isn't going to be worth it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with citizenship law rather than travel.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Seems pretty squarely about travel to me. What else is a passport for?

Comment: Are you irish now? Lahore is in Punjab, now in Pakistani punjab.